# Write a query to output the start and end dates listed by the number of days it took to complete in ascending order

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle19c

**Query for creating table**

```
CREATE TABLE "HR"."PROJECT" 
("TASK_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"START_DATE" DATE, 
"END_DATE" DATE, 
CONSTRAINT "CITI_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("TASK_ID")
)
```

**Query for inserting data**

```
Insert into HR.PROJECT (TASK_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE) values (1,to_date('01-11-21','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('02-11-21','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into HR.PROJECT (TASK_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE) values (2,to_date('02-11-21','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('03-11-21','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into HR.PROJECT (TASK_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE) values (3,to_date('03-11-21','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('04-11-21','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into HR.PROJECT (TASK_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE) values (4,to_date('13-11-21','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('14-11-21','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into HR.PROJECT (TASK_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE) values (5,to_date('14-11-21','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('15-11-21','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into HR.PROJECT (TASK_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE) values (6,to_date('28-11-21','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('29-11-21','DD-MM-RR'));
Insert into HR.PROJECT (TASK_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE) values (7,to_date('30-11-21','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('01-12-21','DD-MM-RR'));
```

**Here is the Table**

[image]

**Output required**

[image]

**Explanation**

Project 1: Tasks 1, 2 and 3 are completed on consecutive days, so these are part of the project.   Thus start date of project is 01-11-2021 and end date is 04-11-2021, so it took 3 days to complete the project.

Project 2: Tasks 4 and 5 are completed on consecutive days, so these are part of the project. Thus, the start date of project is 13-11-2021 and end date is 15-11-2021, so it took 2 days to complete the project.

Project 3: Only task 6 is part of the project. Thus, the start date of project is 28-11-2021 and end date is 29-11-2021, so it took 1 day to complete the project.

Project 4: Only task 7 is part of the project. Thus, the start date of project is 30-11-2021 and end date is 01-12-2021, so it took 1 day to complete the project.

***Note :*** If there is more than one project that have the same number of completion days, then order by the start date of the project.

My approach was to use lead and lag function but i am not even close to get answer. Is my approach wrong or any other best way to solve this.

this is what i have tried

```
select * from 
(select lag(end_date) over (order by start_date) as nx_dt1 , start_date from project )
where to_date(start_date,'DD-MM-YYYY') <> to_date(nx_dt1,'DD-MM-YYYY')
order by start_date asc;
```

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT start_date,
       end_date,
       end_date - start_date AS days_to_complete
FROM   HR.project
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY start_date
  MEASURES
    FIRST(start_date) AS start_date,
    LAST(end_date)    AS end_date
  PATTERN (first_date successive_dates*)
  DEFINE
    successive_dates AS PREV(end_date) = start_date
)
ORDER BY start_date DESC
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

> | START_DATE | END_DATE | DAYS_TO_COMPLETE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2021-11-30 00:00:00 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | 1 |
> | 2021-11-28 00:00:00 | 2021-11-29 00:00:00 | 1 |
> | 2021-11-13 00:00:00 | 2021-11-15 00:00:00 | 2 |
> | 2021-11-01 00:00:00 | 2021-11-04 00:00:00 | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8ee74760c6ac63a73c1d4397fb7d1e8c)*

Answer (score 1):

I gave this a try too MATCH_RECOGNIZE in the previous answer is interesting and something I have never seen before. I came up with something very different.

```
with P (TASK_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE) as( 

    select 1,to_date('01-11-21','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('02-11-21','DD-MM-RR') from dual union all
    select 2,to_date('02-11-21','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('03-11-21','DD-MM-RR') from dual union all
    select 3,to_date('03-11-21','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('04-11-21','DD-MM-RR') from dual union all
    select 4,to_date('13-11-21','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('14-11-21','DD-MM-RR') from dual union all
    select 5,to_date('14-11-21','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('15-11-21','DD-MM-RR') from dual union all
    select 6,to_date('28-11-21','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('29-11-21','DD-MM-RR') from dual union all
    select 7,to_date('30-11-21','DD-MM-RR'),to_date('01-12-21','DD-MM-RR') from dual 
    )
    select task_id, START_DATE,substr(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(end_date, '/'),2,10) end_date,level days_took_to_complete 
    from p 
    where 
    CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF =1 
    start with   end_date not in (select start_date from p)
    connect by nocycle end_date = prior start_date
    order by level,START_DATE desc
```

Comment: Would a union of the `select`s be a possible optimization one could think of to let the machine do its magic?

Comment: @TedLyngmo are you thinking of the (quite unnecessary)   "union all" statements in the WITH clause then you are absolutely right - they could be just "union". But since the WITH clause is used as a container for the sample data I was not too bothered.  If you are thinking of using UNION in the solution I do not see how. But knowing you - you could probably solve it only using Unions. Good to hear from you mate!

Comment: Cheers! Oh, my SQL mojo is almost dead by now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

My MySQL solution below:

```
WITH a
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT Row_number()
                           OVER (
                             ORDER BY start_date) project_id,
                         start_date
         FROM   projects
         WHERE  start_date NOT IN (SELECT end_date
                                   FROM   projects)
         ORDER  BY start_date),
     b
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT Row_number()
                           OVER (
                             ORDER BY end_date) project_id,
                         end_date
         FROM   projects
         WHERE  end_date NOT IN (SELECT start_date
                                 FROM   projects)
         ORDER  BY end_date)
SELECT start_date,
       end_date
FROM   a
       INNER JOIN b using (project_id)
ORDER  BY ( end_date - start_date ),
          start_date;
```